# Integration AWS Cognito with Okta

Tags: amazon-cognito, okta, federated-identity

I am using AWS Cognito User pools to SignUp users. However my client applications are OKTA based. Once the users have signup and confirme their email address on cognito, I would like to be able to login with their credentials directly in the Okta apps, so that would require to create a user/password also on the Okta app. But that would require some development to take the cognito credentials and creating the Okta user with these credentials.

How can I integrate it directly, so once the user has confirmed the email, can automatically log into okta app? Also, if I invalidate a user on cognito, it should not have no longer access to Okta apps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You would need to do all by hands: creating/modifying users in Okta after you do the same in Cognito.

All Okta - Cognito integrations suppose that you have your applications integrated with Cognito, which is integrated with Okta. Okta is your identity store and all creations/modifications are done there. Cognito only trusts information from Okta and allows user to sign-in into applications integrated with it

Comment: Hi Philipp Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, I can use a hook to be executed after every creation/modification of users and then synchronize this in Okta, however I can't access the password from Cognito that the user set, only the email, but I need both, user and password in order to create the Okta user. Any idea how I can handle this?

Comment: Sorry @fgonzalez, that might be a question to Cognito profies. I'd say, if you don't allow users to create users in Cognito directly, but only through a controlled by you interface, then you might be able to capture password